# I am new to Pandas and Python. I am struggling with syntax of & and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains scores for math and reading. I need to find the number of overall passing students that both have a score of 70 or higher in math and reading. I can get this to work for each column but whe I try to use the & condition i get an error
The data Looks like this:
Student Name   School Name reading_score    Math_score
Paul             Huang         66             79
Victor           Huang         94             61
Kevin            Bailey        90             60
Richard          Cabrera       67             58
Bonnie           Holden        75             82

These work alone:

```
overall_passing = school_data_complete.loc[(school_data_complete['math_score'])>=70].groupby('school_name') 

overall_passing2 = school_data_complete.loc[(school_data_complete['reading_score'])>=70].groupby('school_name')
```

This is broken when I use the &

```
op = school_data_complete.loc[[(school_data_complete['math_score'])>=70].groupby('school_name') & [(school_data_complete['reading_score'])>=70]].groupby('school_name')
```

### Here is the error I get:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-bebc440f7525> in <module>
  5 overall_passing = school_data_complete.loc[(school_data_complete['math_score'])>=70].groupby('school_name')
  6 overall_passing2 = school_data_complete.loc[(school_data_complete['reading_score'])>=70].groupby('school_name')
----> 7 op = school_data_complete.loc[[(school_data_complete['math_score'])>=70].groupby('school_name') & [(school_data_complete['reading_score'])>=70]].groupby('school_name')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

Comment: Please edit your question so that code is properly formatted as code

Answer (score 0):

In your second attempt, you are placing the `.groupby()`  inside the `.loc[]` statement. It should be outside.

What about:

```
op = school_data_complete.loc[(school_data_complete['math_score'] >= 70) &
(school_data_complete['reading_score']>=70)].groupby('school_name')
```

Please, take the time to appreciate I also eliminated some `[]` you entered -- but I left the `()` between the two conditions inside the `.loc[]`.

Comment: Thank you this is getting me close but now I have a syntax error with your recommendation.  File "<ipython-input-32-586a4fbd5edc>", line 13
    op = school_data_complete.loc[(school_data_complete['math_score'])>=70) & school_data_complete['reading_score'])>=70].groupby('school_name')
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You have an unmatched `)` at the end of the first boolean statement... `['match_score'])>=70)`

Answer (score 0):

Simplicity is more clear, let us get target easily and in a systematic way, try to reformat  some codes in the question:

Simpify:

```
overall_passing = school_data_complete.loc[(school_data_complete['math_score'])>=70].groupby('school_name')
```

to

```
select = (school_data_complete['math_score']>=70)
overall_passing = school_data_complete.loc[select].groupby('school_name')
```

and in a similar way:

```
select = (school_data_complete['math_score']>=70) & (school_data_complete['reading_score']>=70)
overall_passing = school_data_complete.loc[select].groupby('school_name')
```

and usually, we mention to `select` as `mask`